# In TeamCity is there a way to get a dropdown menu prompt when building to choose a build dependency?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, building, teamcity-9.0

I would like to get a drop-down menu or prompt when I run a build with a build dependency, to choose an older build to use in that dependency. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the ... button next to the Run / Deploy button a popup will appear. Under the dependencies tab you can select an older dependency. This won't cause a prompt to appear when you click the standard Run / Deploy button, but it will allow you select an older dependency as a one off.

Comment: Thank you, didn't see that setting there. Exactly what I needed!